# sassc-rails: Why does math.div(...) not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, ruby-on-rails-7

I am just trying to create a new rails app with Rails 7. I have sassc-rails in my Gem file and seems it's trying to compile various .scss files (I have my own little scss library that I am trying to reuse).
However it struggles as follows:

SCSS:

```
@use "sass:math";
...
$base-border-radius: 1.5rem !default;
$border-radius-s: math.div($base-border-radius, 3);
...
```

Error Message:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...-radius-s: math": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".div($base-border-r"
```

I used exactly the same code with a Rails 6 app and everything compiled properly there, so the scss code itself should be valid?

Answer (score 0):

Update: After switching to cssbuild-rails, everything seems to work.